# Trying to set up multiple asynchrnous React-Redux calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an app working which uses Redux with thunks to get data from an API. This works great!

After fetching page one I want to fetch pages 2, 3 and 4 as well. I add page 2 to page 1 in the store under the items object. And put 3 and 4 in a cache like object called reserveItems to have them ready for the user when he starts scrolling. The trouble I have is due to Javascripts asynchronous nature the code goes past all the increments and all 4 fetch requests end up being for page 1.

I thought I could fix this using promises somehow but I couldn't get it to work, how do I access the props inside the promises and the following then() chain?

Somehow I'm using javascript and thunks wrong. I thought using thunks solved the problem of asynchronous calls, but I can't wrap my head around where in my functions and files to fix this problem.

This is my current chain of functions that need to be called once the user starts a search.

```
    this.props.setPage(page);
    this.props.statsFetchData(this.props.keyword);
    this.props.itemsFetchData(this.props.keyword, this.props.page);
    this.props.incrementPage();
    this.props.itemsFetchData(this.props.keyword, this.props.page);
    this.props.incrementPage();
    this.props.reserveItemsFetchData(this.props.keyword, this.props.page);
    this.props.incrementPage();
    this.props.reserveItemsFetchData(this.props.keyword, this.props.page);
```

This is the items action: https://pastebin.com/ih4TXsSD

And this is the items reducer: https://pastebin.com/p2ZvLpTn
The reserveItems reducer looks basicly the same.

And this was my test of using promises:

```
    const setup = new Promise(function() {
        this.props.setPage(page);
    });

    setup.then(function() {
       this.props.itemsFetchData(this.props.keyword, this.props.page);
    }).then(function() {
        this.props.incrementPage();
    }).then(function() {
        this.props.itemsFetchData(this.props.keyword, this.props.page);
    });
```

Comment: have you tried using async await?

Comment: In promises, you need to return something to preserve the chain. In your case you need to add a return before each `this` in the last example

Comment: I looked up await, I need to learn more about it before I understand how to use it. 
Also, returning in the promises does not solve the fact that I have no props inside the promise

Comment: Do you mean that `this.props` is undefined ? If so, you should also use arrow function into your promises